# HttpXsrfTokenExtractor- getToken() returning null

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

After upgrading angular cli , getToken() of HttpXsrfTokenExtractor returning null , please help

Comment: from where grtToken() of HttpXsrfTokenExtractor takes token??

Comment: How It works...

export declare abstract class HttpXsrfTokenExtractor {
    /**
     * Get the XSRF token to use with an outgoing request.
     *
     * Will be called for every request, so the token may change between requests.
     */
    abstract getToken(): string | null;
}